# CiviPoints - Basics on how to configure and use this extension

Tags: civirules, civipoints

I need some basic guidance on configuring [CiviPoints](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civipoints) and using it. I have installed already on our Wordpress site. But I don't see any simple guide on how to set it up and use it. Simple example with screenshots would do.

PS: I also installed CiviRules. So an example with CiviRules with CiviPoints would be great.

Comment: did you read the notes, and screenshot, here https://civicrm.org/extensions/civipoints

Comment: Yes, I have read the notes and looked at the screenshot. When I add a new contact, I don't see the points tab as per the screenshot.

Comment: best to raise an issue with the extension developers

Comment: I did and will post the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from the developers:

If you want to create a new category of points, this is in the option group "Points Type". Editing option groups can be found somewhere in your admin menus.

A separate points tab will show for each type of points- but only if that contact has previously been granted some points of that type. That can initially be done with the "Grant Points" item in the Actions menu. The points tabs, when visible, also have a "Grant Points" button.

Various permissions are currently required to do stuff with points. The tabs I think require "view all contacts" and granting or deleting require "edit all contacts". With this permission, "Grant Points" appears in the Actions menu. This isn't ideal, perhaps it should check ACLs too but I can't remember how to do this.